# cellForRow(at: indexPath) returns nil and crashes my swift app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitableview

In my `swift` app I'm showing cells in `UITableView`, first 10 cells contain a photo. I've decided to add a parallax effect to each cell, so that when user scrolls the table up and down - the image changes it's offset.

This is how I fetch data from my webservice and initially add it to the tableview:

```
func makePostQueryForFetchingData(_ parameters: [String:AnyObject], url: String, type: String)
{
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: (parameters), encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    items.removeAllObjects()
                    tview.reloadData()
                    if let jsonData = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                        for singleJSON in jsonData {
                            if let single = SingleNode.fromJSON(JSON(singleJSON)){
                                    self.items.add(single)
                            } 
                        }
                    }  
                    self.refreshController.endRefreshing()
                    print("before crash")
                    self.tview.reloadData()
                    print("end")
                })
            case .failure(let error):
               print(error)
            } 
    }
}
```

When I run this function on startup - everything works well. However, if I scroll down the table and then quickly scroll up and pull to refresh - the app crashes.

In pull to refresh I'm calling the function from above.

The function for handling the parallax effect looks like this:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView == self.tview) {
        for indexPath in self.tview.indexPathsForVisibleRows! {
            if (indexPath.row < 10) {
                print(indexPath)
                print(self.tview.cellForRow(at: indexPath))
                self.setCellImageOffset(cell: self.tview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! BigDetailsOnListCell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I realized that when I quickly scroll the table up and refreshes it - I'm seeing in the console:

```
before crash
0
nil
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

so why does the `self.tview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)` returns nil?

Comment: Please also put the code of cellForRow method

Comment: `cellForRow(at:)` returns `nil` if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

Comment: @KuntalGajjar I checked that `cellForRow` is not called at all, I added a `print` msg on the very first line there and it didn't appear. The problem is with this line: `self.tview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! BigDetailsOnListCell` because `nil` cannot be casted to `BigDetails...`. I think that's because my cell is missing, but I'm not sure in which point I'm removing them

Comment: Is your refresh control calling endRefreshing before you get the data back on a pull to refresh?  My thoughts are that it might be since it's being called async.  EDIT: scroll view did scroll gets called when your tableview moves back up after a refresh.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cellForRow(at:)` will only return a cell if the tableview currently has a visible cell for that row.  It will not call your table view's data source method to obtain a cell if there is no visible cell, it will return `nil`.

You need to deal with the fact that `cellForRow(at:)` may return nil.  Don't force unwrap it.  Use a conditional unwrap.  Similarly with `indexPathsForVisibleRows`; there is no good reason to force unwrap that value either.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView == self.tview) {
        if let visiblePaths = self.tview.indexPathsForVisibleRows {
            for indexPath in visiblePaths {
                if (indexPath.row < 10) {
                   if let cell = self.tview.cellForRow(at: indexPath as? BigDetailsOnListCell) {
                    self.setCellImageOffset(cell: cell, indexPath: indexPath as NSIndexPath)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For arrays it's easier to use `?? []`.

Comment: I did have that in my original code for this answer, but I decided to be more explicit. The nil coalescing operator may be a bit "advanced" for those just getting started

Comment: is the `conditional unwrap` in this case equal to `if(self.tview.cellForRow(at: indexPath) != nil){` ?

Comment: Yes. Read about optionals and unwrapping in the Swift Book or in the documentation section of Stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

An index in `indexPathsForVisibleRows` doesn't give you any garanties that the cell is already displayed. Note the difference between *"visible row"* and *"displayed cell"*. A visible row means that the scrolling position is such that the row is or *will* be displayed. It is based on visibility calculations. On the other hand `cellForRow(at:)` is based on the cells currently added as subviews.

Until the cell is actually displayed `cellForRow(at:)` can still return `nil`.

This can happen immediately after calling `reloadTable()` or when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

in pullToRefresh method make yourArray to nil and it will fill with new data when you will get response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is helpful to anyone but it was for me, big time.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.view = nil
    }
```

This is the piece of code that solved my problems. I had encountered an issue right after I sent a new build. The thing is that this bug, that forces the app to crash at this line of code:

```
let guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? YourCustomTableViewCell else {...}
```

I've found out that the crash always occurred when I tried to switch the views fast (I was able to switch the views because they were in a tab bar controller).